# unable to create another actor in Akka WebSocket

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

```
class HomeController  @Inject (implicit actorSystem:ActorSystem, materializer :Materializer) extends Controller 
{ 

    case class sendMsg(msg:JsValue)
    class MYWSACTOR(out:ActorRef,mainActor:ActorRef) extends Actor 
    {

        def receive = 
        {

            case msg : JsValue =>
            mainActor ! sendMsg(msg)

            case sendMsg(msg) => 
            {
                /* validation part */
                out ! msg
            }
        }

    }

}

val mainActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MYWSACTOR],"mainActor")

def object MYWSACTOR 
{
    def props(out:ActorRef) = Props(new MYWSACTOR(out,mainActor))
}

def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue,JsValue] 
{ 
    request =>

    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MYWSACTOR.props(out))

}
```

I am new to Akka and Scala . I am trying to make a chat application using Akka in Scala and Play framework 2.5.3 .I used the above code from the official documentation. I just wanted to create another actor (mainActor in above code) so that message from the client is validated first and  then be sent back. But the problem is mainActor is unable to send the msg to another class case sendMsg. Also , if i try to create the actor at any different point, it gives me compilation error **Unexpected Exception: Provisional Exception**

Comment: Read your code carefully, `MYWSACTOR` takes two arguments, hence `val mainActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MYWSACTOR],"mainActor")` is not valid, you need to pass additional argument.

Comment: I am confused here...since am just creating actor having props of MYWSACTOR class , where I need to pass arguments here? It will be helpful if you will show me as example.

Comment: Read the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Props Your main actor needs two params. But I am wondering who will be its main actor, should it be null? (definitelly not). Maybe you need 2 different classes for those actors.

Comment: I tried with different class for mainActor but when I want to pass that from MYWSACTOR it doesn't work. Actually I am unable to pass the control from out actor to mainActor for any working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is hopefully what you probably wanted:

```
case class SendMsg(msg: JsValue)
case class ReceivedMessage(wsActor: ActorRef, msg: JsValue)

class MyWsActor(out: ActorRef, mainActor:ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case msg : JsValue =>
      mainActor ! ReceivedMessage(self, msg)

    case SendMsg(msg) =>
      out ! msg
  }
}

object MyWsActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef, mainActor: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWsActor(out, mainActor))
  //or if you want to instantiate your Props with reflection
  def props2(out: ActorRef, mainActor: ActorRef) = Props(classOf[MyWsActor], out, mainActor)
}

class MainActor() extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ReceivedMessage(wsActor, msg) => {
      /*
      Do sth with msg
       */
      val result = msg
      wsActor ! SendMsg(result) //here sender is your MyWsActor
    }
  }
}

class HomeController  @Inject() (
    actorSystem: ActorSystem,
    materializer: Materializer
) extends Controller {

  val mainActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MainActor], "mainActor")

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue,JsValue] {
      request =>
        ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MyWsActor.props(out, mainActor))
  }

}
```

The key is that you can send, with actual message, also `ActorRef` (or by default you can get a sender `ActorRef` calling `sender()`) and then you can replay to this ActorRef.